$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ]$ where $W$ and $V$ are independent
Let $V$ and $W$ be independent random variables. Assume that $V$ is standard normal.
We are interested in the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{n  \to \infty}  E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ]
\end{align}
Here is why it is interesting. Depending on the nature of the distribution of $W$ we have can have very different limits.
For example, suppose that $W=c$ a.s.. Then,  for all $n$
\begin{align}
E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ]  = V 
\end{align}
Now suppose that $W$ is absolutely continuous then
\begin{align}
E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V = t] = \frac{\int  v f_V(v) f_W(t - \frac{1}{n}v  ) dv }{ \int   f_V(v) f_W(t - \frac{1}{n}v  ) dv } 
\end{align}
so if  $f_W$ is bounded and continuous density then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ]  = E[V].
\end{align}
I would love to see an argument and understand the tools needed to study this limit. The goal is to get a full picture of this limit.  For example, I am not sure if these are the only two cases. I would also prefer a more measure theoretic argument.
Edit It appears from the discussion that the limit might not even exist. In this case, we would interested in both $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ]$$ and $$\liminf_{n \to \infty}E[V| W +\frac{1}{n}V ].$$

As an intermediate example I’d like to know what happens if $W$ is distributed on the Cantor set with the Cantor measure distribution for example.

@AnthonyQuas Are you imply that the limit might not exist?

I think If W is the sum over i of 2^(-i^2) W_i where the W_i are independent coin flips then the limit didn’t exist. When 1/n is very far away in order from a square power of 2 then we will be able to recover V almost exactly from the sum, but not when it is close to such a power.

@tmh thanks.  You see I don't have a good intuition of how to think about this problem. Could you explain a bit more? I would really like to see the tools that are needed to study this.

For what it is worth, if $V \sim \mathcal N(\mu_V, \sigma_V^2)$ and independently $W \sim \mathcal N(\mu_W, \sigma_W^2)$ then $E\left[V \mid W +\frac{1}{n}V =t \right] = \mu_V + \left(t - \mu_W -\frac{1}{n}\mu_V\right)\frac{\sigma_V^2}{n\sigma_W^2+\frac{1}{n}\sigma_V^2}$ which, for $\sigma_W^2>0$, indeed tends to $\mu_V$ as $n \to \infty$.
